# Mysterious CPU load without process

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage

On my new Windows 10 Home Edition Dell XPS 15 7590 I have some background CPU activity popping up regularly without any obvious process causing this load. Even when the System Idle Process is at over 99 % some background task seems to use one logical core at 50 % for some time until it stops again for no apparent reason.

The system is responsive but power consumption, temperature and fan noise go up. So it's annoying.

What is causing this CPU load? How can that be deactivated? How could I investigate this problem further?

More details:

- The load disappears immediately when unplugging the laptop. Power settings for battery and plug-in use are identical, however (at max power saving).
- When regular usage is higher this behavior appears more often and with up to 3 logical cores.
- Disabling disk encryption and Windows defender had no effect.
- Judging by the graph in the task manager, the load seems to be entirely kernel time.

[image: Mysterious CPU load]

Comment: We need the name of the process. Try to catch it using Process Explorer by adding some more columns from the Process Performance tab, perhaps CPU Cycles.

Comment: Tried doing that. I found nothing suspicious, though.

Comment: Have you added the column CPU Cycles to Task Manager? Could you post the result?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and the result looks just like the one posted above.

Comment: I don't see CPU Cycles.

Comment: I just installed a bunch of driver updates from Dell and the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have the same behaviour